Unable to obtain access token with SpringBoot OAuth2RestTemplate using jwt token client assertion
I'm trying to modify some code to use a jwt cleint assertion instead of a client secret to obtain an access token and id token.
The following code works fine when using a client secret, but gets an error message when using a jwt client assertion:
   @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = ApLoginSettingsConstants.AUTH_PROVIDER, havingValue = ApLoginSettingsConstants.OPENID)
    public JwtOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails platformOpenIdClient() throws ConfigurationException, InvalidAttributeValueException {

        System.out.println("in platformOpenIdClient");
        ApLoginOpenIdSettings openIdSettings = apLoginSettingService.getOpenIdSettings();
        JwtOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details = new JwtOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails();

        // Set client details
        details.setClientId(openIdSettings.getClientId());
        if (useClientSecret){
            details.setClientSecret(decryptionService.decryptTextUsingPlatformKeys(openIdSettings.getClientSecret()));
        }
        else {
            // Generate JWT token
            String clientAssertion = getJwt(); // returns the required JWT
            // Set JWT details
            details.setClientAssertion(clientAssertion);
            details.setClientAssertionType("urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer"); // Set the appropriate client assertion type

        }

        details.setAccessTokenUri(openIdSettings.getTokenUrl());
        details.setUserAuthorizationUri(openIdSettings.getAuthorizationUrl());
        details.setScope(Arrays.asList(openIdSettings.getScopes().split(",")));
        details.setPreEstablishedRedirectUri(openIdSettings.getRedirectUrl() + ApLoginSettingsConstants.OPENID_AUTH_ENTRY);
        return details;
    }

   


    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = ApLoginSettingsConstants.AUTH_PROVIDER, havingValue = ApLoginSettingsConstants.OPENID)
    public OAuth2RestTemplate platformOpenIdTemplate(final OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) throws ConfigurationException, InvalidAttributeValueException {
        OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(sickPlatformOpenIdClient(), clientContext);

        template.getInterceptors().add(new LoggingRequestInterceptor());
        return template;
    }

    private static String getJwt() {
        // test code for JWT

        String file = "C:\\dev2\\services\\core\\lda-properties\\keystore.p12";
        String password = "mypassword";
        String tenantId = "xxxx";
        String clientId = "yyyyy";

        AzureActiveDirectoryCertificateSignedJwtAssertionFactory factory =
                null;
        try {
            factory = new AzureActiveDirectoryCertificateSignedJwtAssertionFactory(file, password, tenantId, clientId);
        } catch (AzureActiveDirectoryAssertionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        String jwt = null;
        try {
            jwt = factory.createJwtAssertion();
        } catch (AzureActiveDirectoryAssertionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Generated JWT: " + jwt);
        return jwt;
    }

The error message received is:
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidRequestException: AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_id'. Trace ID: 5bf23cf4-3a1d-4e34-b67a-5f3627388200 Correlation ID: 39454273-b248-4888-a818-1aefb966ed20 Timestamp: 2024-09-17 23:34:40Z

Here is the JwtOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetail, which extends AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails to include the jwt assertion parameters:
public class JwtOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails extends AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails {
    private String clientAssertion;
    private String clientAssertionType;

    public JwtOAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails() {
        super(); // sets grants type to authorization code
        setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);
    }

    public String getClientAssertionType() {
        return clientAssertionType;
    }

    public void setClientAssertionType(String clientAssertionType) {
        this.clientAssertionType = clientAssertionType;
    }

    public String getClientAssertion() {
        return clientAssertion;
    }

    public void setClientAssertion(String clientAssertion) {
        this.clientAssertion = clientAssertion;
    }
}

I have been able to successfully retrieve the access and id tokens using python scripts, but the OAuth2RestTemplate must need something to make it work using jwt client tokens which I haven't figured out yet.
I've also been having trouble finding any examples or documentation using OAuth2RestTemplate with jwt client assertions. Any helping solving this issue would be much appreciated.
